# WebKitGTK WebInspector doesn't close

Tags: webkit, gtk3, web-inspector, webkitgtk

I'm working on a project using WebKitGTK and I'm having trouble with the WebInspector after having enabled it using the `enable-developer-extras` property.

I can open it fine, but when I click the close, pop-out into own window, or switch to sidebar buttons they don't do anything. In my application there's literally no way to close WebInspector once you've opened it.

It doesn't appear to be anything I've changed in my code because I remember it working before, but when I check those commits from Git they're now broken as well. At the same time however it does look like something I'm doing because other applications on my computer using WebKitGTK have their WebInspector working perfectly (and yes, I checked out their code).

So my question is: Has anyone faced a similar issue? And does anyone have an idea how it might be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably hitting [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181126). Workaround is to add a dummy call to `webkit_web_view_get_inspector` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my issue! I really appreciate it.

Comment: And a proper fix will be landing in WebKit tomorrow, so you should be able to get rid of the workaround soon.

Comment: Now I've made use of that dummy call to build my own WebInspector window, so while that's nice to know it won't make difference to me.